# Fazer button ser habilitado somente quando radio for selecionado

Tags: javascript, html

Quero fazer o button so seja habilitado quando um dos radio for selecionado em jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var radiosum =  $("input[name='tamanho[]'").on('click'), verificarRadio;

function verificarRadio()
{
        const preenchidos = radiosum.get().every(({value}) => value)
        $('#finaliza').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
}
</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Escolha um tamanho:
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />1
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />2
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />3
<br />
<input type="button" id="finaliza" value="Finalizar" disabled>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Analisando o seu código eu vi que na chamada da função no on click não esta dentro do scopo, você tem que colocar assim ('click',verificarRadio)

E dentro da função basta você verificar se houve um checked no radio com is(':checked').

```js
var element = $("input[name='tamanho'");
element.on('click',verificarRadio);

function verificarRadio()
{
  if(element.is(':checked')){
    $('#finaliza').prop('disabled',false);
  }else{
    $('#finaliza').prop('disabled',true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Escolha um tamanho:
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />1
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />2
<br />
<input type="radio" name="tamanho" />3
<br />
<input type="button" id="finaliza" value="Finalizar" disabled>
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado.